# Executing JavaScript on Another Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

For a website I am creating I have created a few different pages with different graphs on them using the D3.js framework. I am trying to create a single page that pulls the graphs from these pages but I cannot get the scripts on the remote pages to execute properly. Here is the code I am using to try to pull one of the graphs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
  }

  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Successful Response (should be blank):</b>
<div id="success"></div>
<b>Error Response:</b>
<div id="error"></div>

<script>
$( "#success" ).load( "barchartLaunchDay.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "There was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The page is properly accessing the graph page without any errors but it is not displaying/loading the graph. On the graph page, the entire graph is created as SVG elements in a single script and it is not enclosed in a div (I don't know if it should be or not). However when I switch to load a page with text on it, instead of the SVG graph, it works properly so I think the error is because I'm trying to load a script, but I don't know any other way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I can post the graph page code if necessary, thank you.

Comment: Don't think grabbing a page like this actually executes any script attached to it. (can you imagine how easily abused it is?) So either use `iframes` so the other pages have their own javascript context embedded, or just put everything into one page.

Comment: Yes, you either need `iframe`s or some kind of templating/parsing/processing library.  If you're trying to achieve a SPA like app, you might want to look into a SPA framework (such as Angular.JS).